# dev_appserver - How to get error log

Tags: java, google-app-engine, logging, dev-appserver

I use netbeans to develop a gae java app.

When i try to debug by

```
dev_appserver.cmd -p 8962 D:\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Reader\build\web
```

I got `Error 500 null` on `http://localhost:8962`.

I think there is something wrong with my program, I want to get the error log, but `dev_appserver` only show me INFO log, how to get error log?

Answer (score 0):

In Google App Engine Launcher click on "Logs".

Comment: gae java sdk does not contain launcher, should i get a launcher for python?